# backgroundworker blocking MVC controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to run some code from an ASP.NET MVC controller action in a new thread/asynchronously. I don't care about the response, I want to fire and forget and return the user a view while the async method runs in the background. I thought the `BackgroundWorker` class was appropriate for this?

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += Foo;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    return View("Thankyou");
}

void Foo(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Why does this code cause there to be a 10 second delay before returning the View? Why isnt the View returned instantly?

More to the point, what do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just start new thread:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var workingThread = new Thread(Foo);
    workingThread.Start();

    return View("Thankyou");
}

void Foo()
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: Cheers, just wondering why the background worked blocks though?

Comment: You can see BackgroundWorker soucre code to find out. BackgroundWorker is WinForms component and I think it's not correct to use it in ASP.NET.

Comment: Instead of newing up Threads manually you should probably use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

Comment: @Mark Boltuc, true. Also, if you're using .NET Framework 4, you can use TPL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)